# PopulateManagedSchema.aspx The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-assistant

While installing Sitecore 9.3 I am getting this error

```
Error requesting https://us-int-cms.com/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8318558Z ##[debug]At E:\bld\CI1\_work\_tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines_3b5693d4-5777-4fee-862a-bd2b7a374c68\2.0.3\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1:132 char:17
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8331818Z ##[debug]+ throw $errorMessage
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8345903Z ##[debug]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8359676Z ##[debug] + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (Error requestin...404) Not Found.:String) [], RuntimeException
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8372775Z ##[debug] + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error requesting https://us-int-cms.com/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.asp x?indexes=all: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8386260Z ##[debug]
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8408068Z ##[debug]Script stack trace:
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8444460Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, E:\bld\CI1\_work\_tasks\PowerShellOnTargetMachines_3b5693d4-5777-4fee-862a-bd2b7a374c68\2.0.3\PowerShellOnTargetMachines.ps1: line 132
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8456298Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8468037Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 22
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8479152Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 18
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8491019Z ##[debug]at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8510744Z ##[debug]Exception:
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8530055Z ##[debug]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Error requesting https://us-int-cms.com/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8773986Z ##[error]Error requesting https://us-int-cms.com/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8774886Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error]Error requesting https://us-int-cms.com/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
2021-05-20T06:54:11.8802881Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed]
2021-05-20T06:54:11.9205476Z ##[section]Finishing: Sitecore CM Installation
```

I checked the Solr URL, it was opening in the browser and all the cores were available. Also, Sitecore is opening. I can manually go to the control panel and populate/rebuild the indexes, but is there any way to resolve this from the installation only.
Any thoughts!!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing this parameter from **None to Forms** in Web.Config File

```
<authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
```